# Matlab - Transpose a 3D matrix only in the third dimension

Tags: arrays, matlab, transpose, multidimensional-array

I have a 3 x 3 x 2 matrix, for example :

```
M(:,:,1) =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9

M(:,:,2) =
    10    11    12
    13    14    15
    16    17    18
```

and I would like to transpose each `M(:,:,i)`, I mean I would like to have :

```
M(:,:,1) =
     1     4     7
     2     5     8
     3     6     9

M(:,:,2) =
    10    13    16
    11    14    17
    12    15    18
```

How is it possible to do this without loops ?
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's what [`permute`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) does:

```
result = permute(M, [2 1 3]); %// swap dimensions 1 and 2
```